# Doubles meant to divide add?

Tags: c++, debugging, double, visual-studio-debugging

I am making a c++ program which functions as a calculator. Everything works except for the division function, which adds the doubles for some reason. Anyone have a fix?

I have tried explicitly casting to a double and banging my head on my desk. Here are a few snippets of my code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void divide()
{
    //first number
    cout << "What is the numerator?";
    double firstNum = 0;
    cin >> firstNum;
    //second number
    cout << "What is the denominator?";
    double secNum = 0;
    cin >> secNum;
    //multiplying
    double answer = firstNum/(double)secNum;
    cout << "Your answer is " << answer << ".";
}

int main() 
{
    //asks for what operation user would like to use
    cout << "Do you want to add, subtract, divide, or multiply? Type [1] for add, [2] for subtract, [3] for divide, and [4] for multiply(minus the brackets).";
    double opquery = 0;
    cin >> opquery;

    // if division
    if (opquery == 3)
    {
        divide();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I would have expected something like `4/4` to equal `1`, but it just returns addition

UPDATE: FULL CODE CAN BE FOUND AT `https://github.com/hoverdoge/cppcalculatorerror/blob/master/code`

Comment: I don't see any way that the code you've posted can produce the problem you describe; there's no way that the floating point division operator can perform addition. Is that your actual code, copied and pasted directly into your question?  What are the values you're providing to `divide()`? Also, why are you using `double opquery` to get an integer value (1 through 4) for the operator? `double` should be used fof floating point values, and your operator choices are not floating point.

Comment: The problem is probably not where you are looking. I suggest trying to strip your actual program down to a minimal, simplified example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi friend, I can't find anything wrong with your code above. I copy your code into a new empty C++ project, and the result for 4/4 equals 1. Anything seems to work well. So could you share a screenshot here about your command window?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Don't encourage people to post screenshots of text. Instead, ask for [mcve] if the posted code does not reproduce the problem. At OP: Besides an actual MCVE (read the link above on how/why) also post your input/output as plain text. But I assume the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @chtz THX a lot :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because as it is, this clearly does division as intended: https://ideone.com/avbjXL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, the code you share here is ok and the result of 4/4=1.
>
> But the code you share in the github has something different. Remove
>   the `;`after `if (opquery == 1);` The program can work normally.

Changes from:

```
if (opquery == 1);
    {
        add();
        return 0;
    }
```

To:

```
if (opquery == 1)
    {
        add();
        return 0;
    }
```

**Note**: When you add the extra `;`after if(xxx), **whatever the value of opquery is**, the main method will execute steps below:

```
cout << "xxx...";
int opquery = 0;
cin >> opquery;
add();
return 0;
```

That's why this issue occurs.